# SQL Deleting/Replacing a part of a string

Tags: sql

Hello I have a problem

I have Column data in string format in this format:

```
xxxxxxxx <***********>
```

I want to pertain the `xxxxxxx`, but get rid of `<***********>`, where `<***********>` could be any type of string of any length.

I have this command so far, but I cant wrap my head around the rest of it.

```
update Claims
set ClaimInitiatedBy = REPLACE(ClaimInitiatedBy,LIKE '% <%>','')
where ClaimInitiatedBy LIKE '% <%>'
```

This command doesn't work, and I know it's because of the 2nd parameter in the REPLACE function.  What should be the 2nd parameter be for this to work?

I'm using SQL Server 2008, if that matters.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you seen this link? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173746.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @s as varchar(50)
set @s = 'axxxxxxxx <*****>'
select substring(@s, 1, charindex('<', @s) - 1)
```

**Output:**

```
axxxxxxxx
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  Got it working.  I had to do this workaround to make it work though  `select substring(@s, 1, charindex(' <', @s))` with a space before the < and taking away the -1, since that was giving the sql engine a fit for whatever reason.  Anyways, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

SELECT REPLACE('abcdefghicde','cde','xxx');

will return abxxxfghixxx

Arguments:

REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )

string_expression

```
Is the string expression to be searched. string_expression can be of a character or binary data type.
```

string_pattern

```
Is the substring to be found. string_pattern can be of a character or binary data type. string_pattern cannot be an empty string ('').
```

string_replacement

```
Is the replacement string. string_replacement can be of a character or binary data type.
```